# Check if a value exists in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My problem is that I have to create a procedure that has to check if a certain value exists in a table and if it does exist it has to delete some rows from a different table. So far I have tried using a `select count(*) from (the select statement) as numOfRows;` command but as far I have seen and searched on the internet it only returns the number of rows, without having the possibility to use it further. 
I`m interested if there is a way to create something like this:
`if (the value exists in the table) then 
 
              -- do whatever it has to be done`

Any idea is welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to paramatize statements to avoid SQL Injection but the following should give you a general idea.

```
delete from table_2
 where id = @id
   and exists ( select 1
                  from table_1
                 where id = @id )
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. In the end the command ended up something like this 'IF NOT EXISTS (the select statement) THEN delete what it has to be deleted and manage the other operations.' Thanks a lot Ben, you saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for MySQL if is:

```
SELECT IF(count(<field_in_question>), <do_this_if_true>, <do_this_if_false>) 
FROM <your_table> 
WHERE field_in_question='<some_value>'
```

You should be able to select the count and if it is greater than 0 do a delete or set a value you can use to flag a delete later on in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved this way (it is not the most fancy way but it works):

```
declare @InList int=0;  
select @InList =count(*) FROM tblOne where fieldOne = @ValueOne

BEGIN TRAN  
IF @InList > 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblTwo WHERE fieldTwo=@valueTwo) 
            BEGIN
                Delete from tblTwo where fieldTwo=@valueTwo
            END 
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

regards,